# pass a variable into curl_easy_setopt C++

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

how to pass a global variable into curl_easy_setopt

```
int agent_num = rand() % 100000;
std::string agent_name = "https://127.0.0.1:443/agent/" + agent_num;

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, agent_name);
```

Ive tried different things and they give giving me a seg fault any help thanks!

Comment: _"...Strings passed to libcurl as 'char *' arguments,..."_ https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html

Comment: _Ive tried different things_ - which was for example...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::string` is not automatically converted to `char *`. Use its [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method for that:

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, agent_name.c_str());`